# Hardware or VST alternatives to Boom3D or FXsound

Tags: effects, vst

I usually play music in MAC OSX with Boom3D audio enhancer software and it has awesome quality for playback. When I play live instruments and MIDI, setting output to Boom3D sound output, it has noticeable latency. I am looking for same alternatives of Boom3D like enhancements in VST plugins or hardwares, Please recommend me if anyone have experience with sound enhancement.

Comment: Boom3D - blowing up laptop speakers since 2007. Avoid like the plague.

Comment: Welcome! Questions about recommendations like gear are not one of the [topics covered here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Maybe the best approach is to ask yourself what it's *doing* to the audio that you like? and then the best way to have the same effect. Maybe it's as simple as EQ? compression?